# How to create element from string

Tags: java, xml, jdom

When we tried to parse the node content and converted to string, the string content is generated like displayed below,

```
&l t; rootNode &g t;
......
&l t;/rootNode &g t;
```

When we tried to add the string content again in an XML using JDOM Element, it is expected to append as shown below, instead we are getting the value as the same shown above without the unicode conversion process.

```
<rootNode>
 .....
</rootNode>
```

We have tried StringUtils, XMLEscapeUtils but we are not getting the expected result, can someone guide me on the right path.

### Edit

**Adding code from OP's comment:**

```
String inputStr = "<rootnode></rootnode>";
org.jDom.Element Element e = new Element("parentnode");
e.addContent(inputStr);
```

Comment: did you try writing a simple xml parser for your needs?

Comment: We had tried but still we are facing issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem:** [JDOM's **`Element.addContent(String)`**](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/Element.html#addContent(java.lang.String)) is adding your `inputStr` as an *unparsed* string.

**Solution:** Instead, you need to parse the string into an element, then add it to `e`.  You'll have to read it into its own document, then detach and move it over.  Here's a sketch:

```
import org.jdom.Element;
import org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder;
import org.jdom.Document;
import java.io.StringReader;
....   
String inputStr = "<rootnode></rootnode>";
Element e = new Element("parentnode");
StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(inputStr);
SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
Document doc = builder.build(stringReader);
Element rootE = doc.getRootElement();
e.addContent(rootE.detach());  // <== Add an Element rather than a String
```